# Returned error: unknown account Web3.js

Tags: web3js, nodejs, gnosis-safe, polygon, safe-core-sdk

I'm trying to create new safe wallet for my current wallet using deploySafe method.
Following is my implementation:

```
import Safe, {
  SafeAccountConfig,
  SafeFactory,
  Web3Adapter,
  Web3AdapterConfig,
} from '@safe-global/protocol-kit';
import { Web3, Web3BaseProvider } from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com'));

const ethAdapter = new Web3Adapter({
  web3,
  signerAddress: SAFE_OWNER_ADDRESS,
});

const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({
  ethAdapter,
});
const signer = await ethAdapter.getSignerAddress();
const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
  owners: [signer],
  threshold: 1,
};


await safeFactory.deploySafe({
  safeAccountConfig,
});
```

SAFE_OWNER_ADDRESS is valid because I can get balance in matics, but Web3 Library always throws following error:

```
Returned error: unknown account
InvalidResponseError: Returned error: unknown account
at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (/Users/macuser/Desktop/work/node-seedhunter/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-core/src/web3_request_manager.ts:363:11)
at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (node-seedhunter/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-core/src/web3_request_manager.ts:207:16)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (node-seedhunter/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:21:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Can Someone please help what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpProvider` is [deprecated](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3.html#providers). Try passing the URI directly to the Web3 constructor.

```
const web3 = new Web3("https://polygon-rpc.com");
```

Use `WebsocketProvider` for legacy browsers.

Comment: I got the same error(